# Geopostion field is required

Tags: django, python-3.x

[image: Address error]

I enter all values correctly but when I hit save it gives following error. I don't know why. My model is as:

```
class Shops(models.Model):
    shopkeeper = models.ForeignKey(Shopkeeper, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = GeopositionField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    contactNumber = models.BigIntegerField()
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Please help me.